# DateTime group by hour in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datetime, group-by

I want to group by on Hour and in select column "time" I want to show full time format (Example: 12:15:56 PM)
but when I run may code the following error is showing.

Error: Column 'vFlowRate_hr.Time' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
select Sum(Value) As FlowRateSum, Dir.PlantAddress, PlantType, FlowRateNo,vFlowRate_hr.Date , time 
from vFlowRate_hr Inner Join DIR ON vFlowRate_hr.FlowRateID = DIR.ID
where FlowRateID = @FlowRateID and DIR.PlantType = @PlantType
and vFlowRate_hr.Date BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
group by FlowRateNo,Dir.PlantAddress,PlantType,vFlowRate_hr.Date, DATEPART(Hour, time)
```

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  It seems quite clear.

Comment: You have `DATEPART(Hour, time)` in the `GROUP BY` clause but just `time` in the `SELECT` list... SQL Server wants it consistent ;-)

Comment: Since you are grouping by datepart(hour,time), your time in the select has to be either an aggregate i.e. max(time) or match your group by datepart(hour,time)

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you want the hour:

```
select Sum(Value) As FlowRateSum, Dir.PlantAddress, PlantType, FlowRateNo, vFlowRate_hr.Date,
       datepart(hour, time)
 from vFlowRate_hr Inner Join
      DIR
      ON vFlowRate_hr.FlowRateID = DIR.ID
 where FlowRateID = @FlowRateID and DIR.PlantType = @PlantType and
       vFlowRate_hr.Date BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
 group by Dir.PlantAddress, PlantType, FlowRateNo, vFlowRate_hr.Date,
       datepart(hour, time)
```

Then the `select` will match the `group by`.

Note that I changed the `group by` so the columns are in the same order as in the `select` -- easier to validate.

Also, you should qualify *all* column references, so it is clear where they come from.  As is, the query will still run but it is less maintainable and updatable with the potentially ambiguous column references.

Comment: I understand but I want to select full time format (hh:mm:ss am) on my report and group by on hour.

Comment: Datepart only shows hour but I want to show time "hh:mm:ss am" in this format. Please help me!

Comment: @NabeelYousaf . . . That doesn't make sense.  I mean, you could use `min(time)` if that is what you want.

Comment: Thanks!. Issue is resolved with your suggestion. It works fine.